# what is the value of $\sum_{i=1}^ni^m$

Tags: calculus

I know that $$\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ can be proved using Gauss method , and 
$$\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$
can be proved using induction method, 
what is the value of $$\sum_{i=1}^ni^m$$